# UITouch Force on touchesBegan

Tags: ios, iphone, uitouch, 3dtouch

3D touch seems really cool and I wanted to see how it would work in a musical context. I was reading a bit about 3D touch and it seems like the `force` property almost always reads as 0 when a touch begins (`touchesBegan` method).

How do I get a usable `force` when a touch begins because even if I'm pressing with maximum "force" I'm still getting that initial 0? I was thinking about just approximating a value within a time frame but that would involve me moving the touch. I just want a usable force upon the first touch.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately this is impossible.

Every touch starts as a contact with no force at all, as soon as the user's finger makes contact (or even near-contact) with the screen. The force only starts to build as the user's finger is compressed against the screen.

The only way for `touchesBegan:` to report any force at all would be for it to delay artificially for a certain number of milliseconds before reporting a touch, to allow the force to build up. This would destroy the interactivity of all iOS applications; and Apple put a huge amount of work into delivering a touch the instant it is detected.

Comment: Ah I was afraid this was the case. I'll give you the bounty because you answered my question! Thanks