# Has Apple deprecated iPhone 3D touch in Swift?

Tags: ios, iphone, 3dtouch, force-touch

I made a game 2 years ago using the 3D touch feature in Swift because it was pretty new but I've never released the game because I got a new contract. Now I have time I want to release it but the code doesn't work any more. (3D touch custom actions, not the peek & pop action)

When I print the touch result, the force value will always return 0.0 like this:

`[<UITouch: 0x102613850> phase: Began tap count: 2 force: 0.000 window: <UIWindow: 0x10222bf70; frame = (0 0; 414 896); gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x28011cde0>; layer = <UIWindowLayer: 0x280f41840>> view: <UIView: 0x102083080; frame = (0 82; 414 780); autoresize = RM+BM; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x2801a0c30>; layer = <CALayer: 0x280f2a540>> location in window: {299.33332824707031, 661.66665649414062} previous location in window: {299.33332824707031, 661.66665649414062} location in view: {299.33332824707031, 579.66665649414062} previous location in view: {299.33332824707031, 579.66665649414062}]`

I know Apple is removing this feature from devices cause of the cost but as I remember, the iPhone 11 pro still has it. Does anyone know if this value is deprecated?

Answer (score 5):

> Every touch starts as a contact with no force at all, as soon as the
>   user's finger makes contact (or even near-contact) with the screen.
>   The force only starts to build as the user's finger is compressed
>   against the screen. [UITouch force on touchesBegan is zero](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38208377/1180728)

---

> **Force Touch**
>
> The technology was first unveiled on September 9, 2014, during the
>   introduction of Apple Watch. Starting with the Apple Watch, Force
>   Touch has been incorporated into many products within Apple’s lineup.
>   This notably includes MacBooks and the Magic Trackpad 2. The
>   technology is known as 3D Touch on the iPhone models. [source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Force_Touch)

These devices support Haptic Touch:

- iPhone 11
- iPhone 11 Pro
- iPhone 11 Pro Max
- iPhone XR

These devices support 3D Touch:

- iPhone 6s
- iPhone 6s Plus
- iPhone 7
- iPhone 7 Plus
- iPhone 8
- iPhone
  8 Plus
- iPhone X
- iPhone XS
- iPhone XS Max

Datasource (2020 January) [Change 3D or Haptic Touch sensitivity on your iPhone](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT205056)

**Solution**

Check a presence of 3D Touch on a device

```
if traitCollection.forceTouchCapability == .available {

}
```

> The iOS trait environment is exposed though the traitCollection
>   property of the UITraitEnvironment protocol. This protocol is adopted
>   by the following classes: UIScreen, UIWindow, UIViewController,
>   UIPresentationController, and UIView. [source](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitraitcollection)

Comment: Ok, I was not tuned. There's a distinct difference between 3D and haptic touch. 
I want to use the 3D touch which is not supported by new iPhones anymore. 
Sorry for the easy answer, I was confused with the answers I found online.

Comment: @Matt I added extra info: Every touch starts as a contact with no force at all, as soon as the user's finger makes contact (or even near-contact) with the screen. The force only starts to build as the user's finger is compressed against the screen.